# How to stock the data obtained from JSON in variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Okay I am a newbie in web developing and it's been hours I am trying to figure out how to stock data into variables in order to use them in other functions.

Here is what I am trying to do :-

```
(function($){
var Rows;
var Cols;

 function initBoard(link) {

        $.getJSON(link,function(data){
              Rows=data.nRows;     

  });
  $div = $('#container');
      for(var i = 0; i < Rows; i++) {....}
......
```

this is a long function to draw a Grid from the JSON file.So at the end I call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
initBoard("easy.json");
 });

   })(jQuery);
```

And then it draws the thing.
The problem is that it seems that nothing gets stocked into my variable Rows..

Even when I try with alert(Rows), nothing happens.

I tried another version doing this :-

```
(function($){


  var dataR;


    function test(link){

  $.getJSON(link,function(data){
      dataR=data.nCols;
      dataC=data.nRows;
      alert(dataR);  // Gives me 13 as Well, DATA READED and stocked..
  });
     alert(dataR);    // Gives me undefined..
    };

 function initBoard() { .... // 
   the function I call to draw the grid, but I want to use the global var
 dataR inside..
.
.// functions I use 
$(document).ready(function() {
initBoard("easy.json");
test("easy2.json");
 });

 })(jQuery);
```

Thank you forgiving me hints or showing help.

Comment: Well yeah.  Your ajax call goes off on its own thread to get the data from the json, but you try to do stuff with the data *before* that part's done!  Use the success callback to do stuff with the data.  Statements occurring after the end of the getJSON block happen right away, before the getJSON block is complete.

Comment: This is because $.getJSON is an asynchronous function. What does this mean? this means that whenever $.getJSON is called, it makes call to the fetch the json and does not block the code written just next after it.

Comment: Okay I merged the two functions inside each others and now it works.

I mean I have copied the body of init() inside test().

and then I can use stocked data into variables in the copied body of init().. is this a good idea ?

Comment: Problem Solved thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a global variable in javascript at the top of your code

```
var _dataToStock;
//your code here
_dataToStock=dataR;//Put this where you get desired value.
```

Now you can use _dataToStock variable to perform othe actions.
Be sure to check value of _dataToStock for null and undefined before use.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. This is because, you are loading data via asynchronous ajax call and while the data is being loaded, your next line of code is executed, in which you are accessing variable, which has not been initialized yet, because ajax call is still in progress.

**How to resolve:** Either put your code block in the success callback or wrap your code block in a function and call this function in the success callback of your ajax call. This will results in, you will be able to access the intiaited variable.

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
var globalVariable = [""];

$(function() {
    initBoard(link);
    printData();
});

 function initBoard(link) {

    $.getJSON(link,function(data){
        var rlen = data.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < rlen; i++)
        {
            globalVariable.push(data[i]);
        }  
    }

});

function printData(){
    try{
        for(i = 0;;i++){
            try{
                if(String(globalVariable[i]) == 'undefined'){
                    break;
                }
            }catch(e){
            }
            alert(globalVariable[i]);
        }
    }catch(e){

    }
}
```